# Customizing Woocommerce Loop Query

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to display my woocommerce products on two different sections on the site i.e. the shop page and on an archive page i created using Custom Post UI plugin, called artists.

Using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, i created a field that will attach each product created to an individual artist. The plan now is, on each artist page, pull products for the artist.

This is what i have so far. I hook into `woocommerce_product_query`, check if i'm on the single artist page and implement my meta query:

```
function artist_products( $query ) 
{
    if( is_singular('artists') )
    {
        $meta_query = ( is_array( $query->get('meta_query') ) ) ? $query->get('meta_query') : [];

        $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => '_fld_select_artist',
                'value' => get_the_ID(),
         );
    
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'artist_products' );
```

This is not working. When i visit my single artist page, i get a 500 server error. What I'm i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`woocommerce_product_query` was breaking my site for some reason so i switched to `pre_get_posts`:

```
function artist_products( $query ) 
{
    if ( $query->get('post_type') == 'nav_menu_item' )
    {
        return $query;
    }

    if( ! is_admin() && is_singular('artists') )
    {
        $meta_query = ( is_array( $query->get('meta_query') ) ) ? $query->get('meta_query') : [];

        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => '_fld_select_artist',
            'value' => get_the_ID(),
            'compare'   => '=',
        );

        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'artist_products' );
```